# Including ShareKit in Three20 project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, three20, sharekit

I have tried including sharekit classes to my three 20 project. All share kit files are dragged into the `Three20Ui.xcodeProject` of three 20. It shows this error Error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../facebook-three20-726841e
>   2/src/Three20UI/SHKOAuthSharer.m'
>
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

`SHKOAuthSharer.m` is afile in share kit.

Where am I going wrong??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be editing the Three20 project directly unless you are altering something that cannot be done with subclassing. Three20 should be added to your project as a subproject. Then, if you want to add other things like ShareKit, you can do it by adding it to your own project, as a sibling to the Three20 subproject.